# CRA getting 404 when path specified

Tags: google-app-engine, create-react-app

I use create-react-app to create a new react app and then run the react dev server.

If I make a naked HTTP request to any URI other than `/` (eg. `/XYZ`), I get a 404.

GAE makes similar naked HTTP calls when doing it's health checks and after quite a bit of pain I found the below to be the reason the Google health checks are failing.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
PORT=8080 npm run start
```

If I telnet to port 8080 and the GET / ... I get a 200 OK.

```
telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1711
ETag: W/"6af-+M4OSPFNZpwKBdFEydrj+1+V5xo"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2023 13:05:00 GMT
Connection: close
```

If however I telnet to port 8080 and get any URI other than / .. I get a 404 (In the below example I request `/XYZ`)

```
telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /XYZ

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 142
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2023 13:09:08 GMT
Connection: close
```

If however I use curl to make that same request I get back a 200 OK

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/XYZ
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /XYZ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.85.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 1711
< ETag: W/"6af-+M4OSPFNZpwKBdFEydrj+1+V5xo"
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2023 13:10:08 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

This became a problem for me because Google App Engine (GAE) has a parameter called `readiness_check` and it seems that GAE makes similar naked http requests to the URI specified for the `readiness_check` parameter.

So I'm looking for a way to have the react app respond with a 200 OK to `/XYZ` when there is no other HTTP headers present. It's clearly possible because it response with a 200 OK to the `/` request.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that telnet still existed and shocked that you can use it with Google cloud.

Comment: Well to be clear I'm not using it with Google cloud, I'm running my CRA app local and using Telnet to send a very simply HTTP request. HTTP is still just a simple Text based protocol.

Comment: If you don't want to use telnet you can use a tool like https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on. You will find that wait-on -v http://localhost:8080/ will work fine, but if you try wait-on -v http://localhost:8080/XYZ it will fail with a 404